# Dapper Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

In the first place i feel thankful for all of 
I have method which call (Read Date) return with( Sql Data Reader "dr")
but after the data return I'm trying to use if `dr.read()` and i get error

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

```
public Calss DB{
public SqlDataReader ReadQuery( string query)
{
    SqlDataReader dr;

    var ConnecRepository = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnecRepository))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        return dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
}
// Page
namespace HomePage
DB db = New DB();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string query = query;
SqlDataReader dr = db.ReadQuery(string.Format(query, Email, Password));
}
if (dr.Read())>>>> here the problem is Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed
{
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided a [MCVE]. You haven't shown where `db` is declared.

Comment: db is the name of the Class who have the Method ReadQuery

Comment: No, `db` is an instance of something. But you haven't shown how you declare it or the definition or anything in your question. Thus you haven't satisfied the criteria of a [MCVE].

Comment: yeh sorry read the code now you would find db is an instance  of the class which have ReadQuery Method  and ReadQuery Method im use it by dynamic way to bind all data readers in my  web

Comment: You need to *show that code in your question*.

Comment: i did you can Read the code now please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlDataReader` requires active `db connection` to go through the records. In your case you are closing the active connection and returning `readar` object and then trying to retrieving records.
That's why you are getting error. reader is closed.

I suggest two approaches to solve your problems.

1 .Read the data from `data readar` when its active like

```
 SqlDataReader dr;

        var ConnecRepository = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
           using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnecRepository))
           {
               connection.Open();
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
               cmd.Connection = connection;
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               cmd.CommandText = query;
               dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          if (dr.Read()){
                 \\your logic here}
        }
```

2. Use adapter to fill the data set and return dataset/data table to the calling program or web page. you can find number of samples how to use dataapter to fill data set.

Hope this helps. let me know if you need further assistance. happy to help!!